# Upon upload, how to send image metadata to MongoDB at the same time image is sent to Cloudinary?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, exif, cloudinary

I would like to upload an image in an express route and save to Cloudinary, while at the same time saving useful metadata (gps data, time created), along with some user defined data from an Image schema, to MongoDB.  Right now Cloudinary stores the image and sends an http filepath to MongoDB.  But I can't seem to find anyway to access the metadata information and send the interesting pieces to MongoDB as well.  I am using Mongoose, Multer, and Cloudinary,

Here is my post route:

```
router.post('/create', fileUploader.single('imageUrl', {image_metadata: true}), (req, res) => {

   
    Photo.create({ imageUrl: req.file.path, metadata: req.file.metadata })
      .then(newlyCreatedPhotoFromDB => {
        res.json({newlyCreatedPhotoFromDB });
        console.log(newlyCreatedPhotoFromDB);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(`Error while creating a new photo: ${error}`));
  });
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: The upload response from Cloudinary should have all the metadata you need when image_metadata=true, you usually get IPTC, XMP, and detailed Exif metadata. Is there a specific metadata you're looking for in the response or did misread the issue?

Comment: I would like the GPS data and Creation Time/Date for the photo.  I think I've determined that it's another package, 'multer-storage-cloudinary', that is preventing me from configuring the upload response from Cloudinary.  Now I just have to figure out how to run Multer and Cloudinary without 'multer-storage-cloudinary' so I can set my own parameters for the Cloudinary response.

Comment: The upload response from Cloudinary is not something you can configure, it is sent by Cloudinary so you would have no way to control what data you receive besides the optional stuff like sending `image_metadata:true` which includes `IPTC, XMP, and detailed Exif metadata`. For your case, I would retrieve the GPS, creation_time etc. from the file using native code then upload the asset to Cloudinary, retrieve the required data from Cloudinary's response, then together store the information to your MongoDB. Hope this helps.